# How to add a linker command line option into meson

Tags: configuration, meson-build

How do we add a linker command line option into meson build system e.g:

If a wanted CL:

```
-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib
```

so it must be found correctly every time the release program is executed, how to set the meson configuration ?

```
.
```

Answer (score 3):

Either from meson setup or configure (assuming the C linker):

```
meson setup -Dc_link_args='-Wl,-rpath=...'
```

OR

```
meson configure -Dc_link_args='-Wl,-rpath=...'
```

Or you could set them in the meson build definitions themselves, if that makes more sense (though generally for things like rpath it makes more sense to set them externally).

```
build_target(
    ...
    link_args : ['-Wl,-rpath=...']
)
```

Comment: …and to add link args to the entire project there's a `add_project_link_arguments()`